# How to write this regex pattern in Swagger?

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger

How to properly define the following regex `pattern` using Swagger Node.js annotations?

```
 *       reviews_ratings_description:
 *         type: string
 *         minimum: 10
 *         maximum: 50
 *         pattern: "^[ a-zA-Z0-9](?!,.*?[^\na-zA-Z0-9!”$%&~^&#<>.?:"'’=@()*\+,\/;\[\\\]\-^_`{|}~]{1}).*?[a-zA-Z0-9!”$%&~^&#<>.?:"'’=@()*\+,\/;\\\\]\-^_`{|}~]$"
```

Running the code above produces the following error:

```
{"error":{},"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: YAMLException: can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 42, column 159:\n     ... \"'’=@()*\\+,\\/;\\[\\\\\\]\\-^_`{|}~]$'\n
```

Does the `pattern` string need to be escaped somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your Pattern contains ", that can't work.

You have to escape the inner quotes by using a backslash in front like \".

Comment: First i've used single quotation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write it in the following pattern:

```
 pattern: ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_=]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+\/=]+)$
```

and if I take your example you should remove the `"` from your regex:

```
 pattern: ^[ a-zA-Z0-9](?!,.*?[^\na-zA-Z0-9!”$%&~^&#<>.?:"'’=@()*\+,\/;\[\\\]\-^_`{|}~]{1}).*?[a-zA-Z0-9!”$%&~^&#<>.?:"'’=@()*\+,\/;\\\\]\-^_`{|}~]$
```

TIP:
use one of the online regex build/test ->https://regex101.com/ (my favorite)